# linking users in the comments with Django

Tags: django, tags, comments

Hello Community I am using Django and I would like to "tag" or "link" users in a comment (like you do it in Facebook or Reddit). The goal should be that the user can write a comment and write a "#" or a "@" to refer to a user in the comment, this user should get some kind f Notification.

I thought to try something with RegEx (like if "#" in comment...) so the username is a link to the profile, but even if i get this to work, i have no idea how to send a user a message/notification that he got mentioned.

Any suggestions how to approach this Problem? Im feeling kind of lost here since i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code you could do something like this, use pythons split and put it in the comment model save method

```
hashtags = comment_string.split('#')
mentioned_usernames = [word[0] for words in hashtags.split(' ', 1)]

for username in mentioned_usernames:
    #get the user
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    #call your function that sends the notification to the user
    send_notification(user)
```

Comment: i went with this and it worked well for the backend. now i am doing the front end part... 
`def userTagComment(self):
  tagUsers = re.findall(r"@+(\w+)", self.content) 
  taggedUsers = list()

  for username in tagUsers:
   try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    taggedUsers.append(user)
   except:
    user = "franz"
    
   notitification(user)

  return taggedUsers`